# shell script - select CSV lines by float value

Tags: shell, csv, cut

I'm stuck with a strange behavior while reading a CSV file and selecting its lines with a specific column float value.

Here's an extract from the input file.

```
ben@truc:$ head summary.fasta.csv
scf7180000753635;170043549;XP_001849446.1;27.72;184;2e-13;74.7
scf7180000753636;340728919;XP_003402759.1;25.78;322;8e-19;93.6
scf7180000753642;328716306;XP_003245892.1;33.51;191;7e-27;119
scf7180000753642;512919417;XP_004929373.1;43.18;132;1e-23;108
scf7180000753642;512914080;XP_004928052.1;40.16;127;5e-21;94.7
scf7180000753664;328696819;XP_003240139.1;37.99;179;2e-23;107
scf7180000753664;328696819;XP_003240139.1;26.67;30;2e-23;25.4
scf7180000753664;328703138;XP_003242103.1;31.65;218;1e-20;99.4
scf7180000753669;383855900;XP_003703448.1;68.92;74;2e-23;102
scf7180000753669;380030611;XP_003698937.1;72.06;68;3e-22;99.8
```

Here's my shell script code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "extracting the values"
# prepare output files
echo "" > "40_sequence_identity.csv"
echo "" > "60_sequence_identity.csv"
echo "" > "80_sequence_identity.csv"
while read -r line; do
    #debug: check if line is correclty read
    echo $line
    #attribute each CSV column value to a variable
    query=`echo $line | cut -d ';' -f1`
    gi=`echo $line | cut -d ';' -f2`
    refseq=`echo $line | cut -d ';' -f3`
    seq_identity=`echo $line | cut -d ';' -f4`
    align_length=`echo $line | cut -d ';' -f5`
    evalue=`echo $line | cut -d ';' -f6`
    score=`echo $line |  -d ';' -f7`

    #debug: check if cut command is OK
    echo "seqidentity:"$seq_identity
    # test float value of column 4, if superior to a threshold, write the line in a specific line
    if [ $( echo "$seq_identity >= 40" | bc ) ]; then
        echo "$line" >> "40_sequence_identity.csv"
    fi
    if [ $( echo "$seq_identity >= 60" | bc ) ]; then
        echo "$line" >> "60_sequence_identity.csv"
    fi
    if [ $( echo "$seq_identity >= 80" | bc ) ]; then
        echo "$line" >> "80_sequence_identity.csv"
    fi
done < "summary.fasta.csv" 
echo "DONE!"
```

And here's the strange outputs.

```
extracting the values
scf7180000753635;170043549;XP_001849446.1;27.72;184;2e-13;74.7
./create_project_directories.sh: 1: ./create_project_directories.sh: -d: not found
seqidentity:27.72
scf7180000753636;340728919;XP_003402759.1;25.78;322;8e-19;93.6
./create_project_directories.sh: 1: ./create_project_directories.sh: -d: not found
seqidentity:25.78
scf7180000753642;328716306;XP_003245892.1;33.51;191;7e-27;119
./create_project_directories.sh: 1: ./create_project_directories.sh: -d: not found
seqidentity:33.51
scf7180000753642;512919417;XP_004929373.1;43.18;132;1e-23;108
./create_project_directories.sh: 1: ./create_project_directories.sh: -d: not found
seqidentity:43.18
scf7180000753642;512914080;XP_004928052.1;40.16;127;5e-21;94.7
./create_project_directories.sh: 1: ./create_project_directories.sh: -d: not found
seqidentity:40.16
scf7180000753664;328696819;XP_003240139.1;37.99;179;2e-23;107
./create_project_directories.sh: 1: ./create_project_directories.sh: -d: not found
seqidentity:37.99
scf7180000753664;328696819;XP_003240139.1;26.67;30;2e-23;25.4
./create_project_directories.sh: 1: ./create_project_directories.sh: -d: not found
seqidentity:26.67
```

First, the 3 output files (blast_summary_superior_40_sequence_identity.csv ...) contain all the lines, as if the tests didn't work.
Second, the file parsing seems OK, but this strange message: -d: not found , comes from nowhere.Though, it appears before the 'echo' displaying the value of $seqidentity and is probably related to the cut command.

Any idea why I have such output ?
When I manually execute the commands in the console, this works.
But not when executing the whole script.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you _really_ have those comments beginning with `//`?

Comment: As an aside, the whole thing would become much easier if you were to use `awk` or `perl`.

Comment: // replaced. Sorry, i just added that for this post. I don't want to use awk because in the future my conditions (the 3 'if') will be used for more complex operations. I really would like to keep this structure.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting Error : `-d: not found`  because on line number 17 command is incomplete

```
score=`echo $line |  -d ';' -f7`
```

So it should be :

```
score=$(echo $line |  cut -d ';' -f7)
```

Comment: oh my god! what a stupid error that blocks me since yesterday!

Comment: Thanks for that.

Can I ask why changing the `` to $() is an improvement ?

Comment: `` is old style, $( ) it's new one and read more http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash